# centos: linking lib that doesn't have a .pc file for pkg-config

Tags: linker, centos, pkg-config, librsvg

I'm trying to compile svg2pdf on centos. I think I've managed to get the required dependencies installed using yum:

```
sudo yum install librsvg2
sudo yum install cairo
```

The Makefile contains:

```
MYCFLAGS=`pkg-config --cflags librsvg-2.0 cairo-pdf` -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -
Wnested-externs -fno-strict-aliasing
MYLDFLAGS=`pkg-config --libs librsvg-2.0 cairo-pdf`
```

After typing 'make', the first couple of lines of output are:

```
cc   `pkg-config --cflags librsvg-2.0 cairo-pdf` -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wnested-externs -fno-strict-aliasing `pkg-config --libs librsvg-2.0 cairo-pdf` svg2pdf.c -o svg2pdf
Package librsvg-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `librsvg-2.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'librsvg-2.0' found
```

There is no librsvg-2.0.pc on this system (but there is when I installed this using macports on my macbookpro).

How should I get this package linked? Should I change the Makefile, and if so, to what? Should I generate the .pc files, and if so, how? Or is there another way to resolve this?

Or, has anyone been successful at installing svg2pdf on centos, and, if so, how did you manage it?

I don't have much experience on linux, so I might be missing something obvious.

Answer (score 3):

I think CentOS uses `-devel` packages. Have you installed `librsvg2-devel` and `cairo-devel`?

Comment: Indeed, I've dealt with this when building rrdtool on RHEL. Dependency hell at its finest.